# Is the server running on host localhost and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I keep getting this error message

"psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Here is the code that is causing the error.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host = config.DB_HOST, database=config.DB_NAME, user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASS, port=config.DB_PORT)
```

and this line

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
```

Comment: What's your question.  Is the server running on port 5432?  Obviously not.  What are you expecting to be there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/screenrwebsiteplzwork/dashboard.py", line 20, in <module>
    connection = psycopg2.connect(host = 'localhost', database='etfdb', user='postgres', password='password', port='5432')
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

Comment: This is the error message i get